# How to find value index and array it belongs within a group of multiple arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 4 arrays, each holds different values relating to hours of the day thus:

```
int[] HourArray1 = {00, 04, 08, 12, 16, 20};
int[] HourArray2 = {01, 05, 09, 13, 17, 21};
int[] HourArray3 = {02, 06, 10, 14, 18, 22};
int[] HourArray4 = {03, 07, 11, 15, 19, 23};
```

Belo is what I have been able to do to get the index of a particular hour and the array where it is located.

```
       private void btnGetHexValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int HourIndex = 0;
        int HourGroup = 0;

        // Hours
        HourIndex = Array.IndexOf(HourArray1, Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")));
        HourGroup++;

        if (HourIndex == -1)
        {
            HourIndex = Array.IndexOf(HourArray2, Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")));
            HourGroup++;

            if (HourIndex == -1)
            {
                HourIndex = Array.IndexOf(HourArray3, Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")));
                HourGroup++;

                if (HourIndex == -1)
                {
                    HourIndex = Array.IndexOf(HourArray4, Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH")));
                    HourGroup++;
                }
            }
```

My request: Is there a better and more efficient approach please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question better?

Comment: Use "HourIndex % 4" which is the MOD function.  The first array is where HourIndex  evenly divides by 4.  Second array is where the remainder is 1.  Third array is where remainder i2.  Fourth array is where remainder is 3.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for code review of working code - there is [codereview.se] which is more suitable for this type of activity. (Note that `DateTime.Now` changes every now and then - so make sure to call it once).

Answer (score 2):

You can put the arrays into another array and use a single LINQ query:

```
int[][] allHours = { HourArray1, HourArray2, HourArray3, HourArray4 };
(int hourIndex, int hourGroup) = allHours
        .Select((arr, ix) => (Position: ix + 1, FoundIndex: Array.IndexOf(arr, DateTime.Now.Hour)))
        .Where(x => x.FoundIndex >= 0)
        .Select(x => (x.FoundIndex, x.Position))
        .DefaultIfEmpty((-1, -1))
        .First();
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ACDrz9

Comment: Many thanks for your response. How do I implement your suggestion in C# winform.

Comment: @Topa: I don't understand your question. My code is not related to winforms/webforms or any other technology. It just relies on `System.Linq` and arrays. I think for the exact syntax you need C#7 or newer(tuple deconstruction etc.).